# Roadmap to the Renormalization Group Approach

Tags: quantum-field-theory, soft-question, resource-recommendations

I am an undergrad interested in HEP-Th. I have studied canonical quantization, and path integral approach for quantizing fields, and the EM field quantization, classical yang-mills theory. I want to learn RG, especially for its utility in HEP. What are the topics that I should learn to get to it, and could you suggest parts of a reference. I know that Peskin and Schroeder is the canonical reference, but I don't know where to start and what is necessary. There seems to be a lot of chapters before I can start RG: radiative corrections (chapter 6 and 7?), systematics (chpt 10), symmetry (11).

How is it organized and what should I read?

Answer (score 4):

If you just wish to understand the concept of Wilsonian RG in field theory then Mehran Kardar's Vol2: *Statistical physics of fields* might be a good resource. The easiest computation is the renormalization (scale dependence) of the quartic coupling in the $\phi^4$ theory. Wilsonian RG is slightly different from what is called "renormalization" and is common in HEP (at least in older textbooks). I am not aware of a good pedagogical reference relating the two perspectives.

Note that you should be able to compute loop amplitudes, in order to calculate any of these these effects. If you're comfortable with that, you might be able to have a go at Sec. 10.1,2 of Peskin & Schroeder. You might also like A. Zee's book: *QFT in a nutshell* which I will generally recommend as a nice read on QFT.